# Problem with removing a dot from unix timestamp in Apache NiFi

Tags: regex, logging, timestamp, apache-nifi

I get input on the log:

> **1518442283.483**     161 127.0.0.1 TCP_MISS/200 103701 GET http://www.cnn.com/ matt DIRECT/199.27.79.73 text/html

but I must have it in this form:

> **1518442283483**     161 127.0.0.1 TCP_MISS/200 103701 GET http://www.cnn.com/ matt DIRECT/199.27.79.73 text/html

I need to remove the dot from unix timestamp using **regex**

Thanks for your help!

Comment: What have you tried? What didn't work? What did you get? What did you expect?

Comment: I want this change in my log: 1518442283.483 → 1518442283483

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with below **Replace Text** configs:

Search Value

```
(.*?)\.(.*)
```

Replacement Value

```
$1$2
```

[image]

**Input:**

```
1518442283.483 161 127.0.0.1 TCP_MISS/200 103701 GET http://www.cnn.com/ matt DIRECT/199.27.79.73 text/html
```

**Output:**

```
1518442283483 161 127.0.0.1 TCP_MISS/200 103701 GET http://www.cnn.com/ matt DIRECT/199.27.79.73 text/html
```

Answer (score 0):

A dot `.`  is a special character in a regular expression meaning any character. to use a literal dot one has to escape it, most of the times by means of a backslash (`\.`). Depending on the usage / language used some more escape characters / backslashes might be necessary.

Comment: When I use this regex, all the dots from the entire log will be removed, and my goal is to remove only the first dot encountered.

Comment: Is the indicated line the only line in the code? is the format always like 10 digits dot 3 digits space?  Maybe necessary to refine regular expression. Show code you use to filer plus (part of) the input file.

Comment: Maybe some information about why you need the change might be useful as well.

Comment: Ok, sure. I use my solution in the Hortonworks Data Platform cluster. The service that supports this case is Apache NiFi. The input data is the log that is given above. Then it separates it so that it can power the Hive database.

The unixtimestamp date will always have the same number of characters, i.e. XXXXXXXXXX.XXX. In order for the input data to be processed, I need to remove the dot after the 10th character.

Comment: so maybe something as regexp like `s/\([0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]\)\.\([0-9][0-9][0-9]\)/\1\2/`. Did you, by any chance, use in the execution of the regular expression the 'g' (global) option? if so be very careful with it.